# using pom.xml instead of iml files in idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

We are using IntelliJ idea in order to develop our product.
till now, we saved the iml/ipr files in a version control in order to share the same configuration among developers (and also between different versions of our product).
however, since idea changes those iml files a lot, it is an exhausted task to resolve its conflicts, and actually feels a bit wrong.
Moreover, idea 15 is no longer checks-out iml/ipr automatically.

I tried the maven-idea-plugin which suppose to generate the iml/ipr based on the pom.xml and it looks promising (except for some minor issues) but it's obsolete and there many stackoverflow posts advise against it.

I also undestand that the "correct way" to load our project is by loading the e pom.xml directly in idea.

The problem with that loading the pom.xml is that each user has to reconfigure idea (such as exclude directories, set the run configuration, plugins, maven version, JDK location etc.) 
every time he download the code from the version control, which happens quite often.

So, my question is what is the best way to use intellij idea with our project.
my goal is that once a developer download the code he will be able run idea without manually configure a thing.

Thanks,
Meir

Answer (score 0):

I am using Intellij 15.0.3 Community edition.
In our current project we do not add *.iml to Git.
For shure we do add pom.xml to Git.
I did not add any special plugins or configure idea in the way you described

> (such as exclude directories, set the run configuration, plugins, maven version, JDK location etc.)

So I am using Idea out of the box, only the plugin 'Maven integration' is activated. I initially cloned the Git repository in a new folder.
In Idea I choosed File| New | 'Project from existing sources ' 
and selected the folder with the pom.xml.
Thats all, works perfectly. I can build in Idea or on the command line.
I can use Git in Idea or on the command line.
Everything works perfect.

So I can asure you that its absolutely possible without having *.iml under version controle.